# Ember.js belongsTo / hasMany relationships with async

Tags: javascript, ember.js

So I've got a model

```
App.DailyEntry = DS.Model.extend({
    user_id: belongsTo('user'),
    entries: hasMany('Entry', {async: true}),
    daily_minutes: attr(),
    entry_day: attr(),
});
```

and I am wondering how I can access the the entries array on the template?

I've tried something like this when in `model context`

so `{{#each entries}}` which doesn't work.. but `{{daily_minutes}}` for example works, so I am in the right context for sure.

I am assuming I need to wait for the `promise` to be fulfilled but I am not sure how to write that logic in the template.

Answer (score 0):

You actually don't need to wait for the promise to fulfill in the template, Ember will handle that for you.  The reason being is it isn't really a promise, it's a promise proxy, meaning it pretends to be an empty array, and when the promise fulfills it populates the array in a way that ember is informed that it's updated.

You'll want to make this lower case (though ember might be forgiving and allow it)

```
App.DailyEntry = DS.Model.extend({
    user_id: belongsTo('user'),
    entries: hasMany('entry', {async: true}),
    daily_minutes: attr(),
    entry_day: attr(),
});
```

Your json response should look like this if you're using the rest serializer (for id 1).

```
{
   dailyEntry: {
     id: 1,
     user_id: 1,
     entries:[1,2,3],
     daily_minutes:'foo',
     entry_day:'bar'
   },
   users:[
    {
      id:1,
      name:'joe blow'
    }
   ]
}
```

Example: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/773/edit